# why MyTextView in android isn't aligned to right?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tipTitleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.me.view.text.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/tipTitleText"
            style="@style/popupTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Tip" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

but my code doesn't change the gravity when ltrMode is on.

I want to change this programmatically.

how come?

```
private void setUpforRTL(){
    if (AppService.getNativeManager().getLanguageRtl()) {

        TextView addText2 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tipText));
        addText2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        TextView title = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tipTitleText));
        title.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

        title.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update

    }

}
```

Comment: no, the other one was in accurate. I changed the xml and question too many times. I flagged the other one to be closed.

Comment: Have you tried changing the parent to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `requestLayout` on the surrounding view after updating the layout parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tipTitleLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.me.view.text.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTitleText"
        style="@style/popupTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain? I want it to be rtl only when rtlmode is on.

Comment: Is it working or not?

Answer (score -1):

Change declaration of title to LinearLayout since you defined it as LL in xml.

Comment: where? I don't get it

Comment: Why -1? TextView title = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tipTitleText));
        title.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

Comment: also watch out with your layout.xml. looks like your doing to much gravity/layout_gravity

Comment: `tipTitleText` is not a linearlayout. where do you see this?

Comment: my fault, sorry, saw tipTitleLayout instead of tipTitleText. try to reduce layout/layout_gravity and margin settings. Try to use Textview without LinearLayout. That`s what I would try.

Comment: it has some siblings. I cannot remove it